# running function(s) on the remote host over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I've a number functions in my scripts:

```
function chk_host() { ...... }
function run_test() { ...... }
```

which I want to run on the remote machine over ssh:

```
ADDR=${ADDR:-"10.192.11.22"}
ssh -T user@${ADDR} << EOF
  chk_host
  run_test
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work as `chk_host` or `run_test` is not a command and not available on the remote host. I suppose, I can do something like: `ssh -T user@${ADDR} "$( declare -f run_test ); run_test << EOF` but I have a number of those and eventually will be running as command-line parameters. What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, the safest way to reach the goal would be to upload a shell script with all necessary functions to a target host, and then running a command via shell, something like `ssh user@${HOST} "source /path/to/uploaded_functions.sh; afunc <args>"`

The prior uploading is useful (although probably not necessary) because evaluating all required functions right in command line may lead to hard problems with proper escaping all special characters and sequences.

Comment: After trying a number of things, the process suggested by 
@user3159253 appeared to be the best. Thanks!